# How to copy files using Set_Monitor function in BATCH file CMD

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I need some help with cmd .bat code. I have a machine which makes different tests. Tests results goes to pc in specific folder. Each test is named automatically as stated in a program. Tests are written in .csv format. Problem is, that each time i make a new test, the older test file is owerwritten. At least i have made bat file, which sets monitor at that folder specific file and copy, rename and write it in specific place. I need that with all my test files, now i have just with one..

This is what i have:

```
@Echo Off
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit
Set _Delay=3

Set _Monitor="c:\Users\Topas\Desktop\Export\Tacktestorezultatai.csv"

Set _Base=%temp%\BaselineState.dir
Set _Chck=%temp%\ChkState.dir
Set _OS=6
Ver|Findstr /I /c:\Users\Topas\Desktop\Export\Tacktestorezultatai.csv>Nul

If %Errorlevel%==0 Set _OS=5 & Set /A _Delay=_Delay*1000
:_StartMon
Call :_SetBaseline "%_Base%" "%_Monitor%"
:_MonLoop

If %_OS%==5 (Ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w %_Delay%>Nul) Else Timeout %_Delay%>Nul
Call :_SetBaseline "%_Chck%" "%_Monitor%"

FC /A /L "%_Base%" "%_Chck%">Nul
If %ErrorLevel%==0 Goto _MonLoop
::
echo %DATE%
echo %TIME%
set datetimef=%date:~-4%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
echo %datetimef%

xcopy /s/z "c:\Users\Topas\Desktop\Export\" "c:\Users\Topas\Desktop\galas"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    for %%f in (Tacktestorezultatai.csv) do (

        set i=0

        for /F "delims=" %%l in (%%f) do (

            set /A i+=1

            set line!i!=%%l

        )

echo %%f, >> bendras.csv
echo  !line2!>> bendras.csv
echo  !line3!>> bendras.csv

    )

ren "c:\Users\Topas\Desktop\galas\" "Tacktestorezultatai_%datetimef%.csv"

::
Echo.Change Detected
Goto :_StartMon
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Subroutine
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:_SetBaseline

If Exist "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir" Del "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir"
For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /S "%~2"') Do (
Set _Last=%%I
>>"%temp%\tempfmstate.dir" Echo.%%I

)
>"%~1" Findstr /V /C:"%_Last%" "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir"

Goto :EOF
exit
```

Tacktestorezultatai.csv is one of the files, which are exported after making a test. There are more files, for example 90laipsniurezultatai.csv  ;   Trintiestestorezultatai.csv  . I want to make the same to these files.

Comment: What is "Set_Monitor"??

Comment: It is a function, that keeps checking if any files has changed in specified folder

Comment: I can't find it anywhere in your code (just in the question title), that's why I ask... is it the name of your batch script when stored to a file??

Comment: Set _Monitor="c:\Users\Topas\Desktop\Export\Tacktestorezultatai.csv"

Comment: `Set_Monitor` is _not_ a function. `_Monitor` is a _variable_. You should change the topic title, that just confuse the real problem (what is the _real problem_?)